# Select first row in each partition of Hive table

Tags: hive, hiveql, greatest-n-per-group, hive-query

I'd like to get the first N records from each partition in a hive partitioned table without having to deserialize every record in the table. I've seen a number of solutions for other databases, but not one that works in Hive without running over every single record.

A minimal example:

```
create table demo ( val int ) 
    partitioned by (partid int);
insert into demo partition (partid=1) 
    select stack(5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
insert into demo partition (partid=2) 
    select stack(5, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500)
insert into demo partition (partid=3) 
    select stack(5, -1, -2, -3, -4, -5)
insert into demo ...
    ...
```

I'd like to get the result of

```
select * from partition_demo where partid = 1 limit 1
union all
select * from partition_demo where partid = 2 limit 1
union all
select * from partition_demo where partid = 3 limit 1
union all
...
```

without writing every single clause, **and** without deserializing all of the data in each partition (which seems to happen using `RANK OVER`).

Comment: Can you post some sample input and expected output? This will make it more clear to us.

Comment: Thanks @MayankPorwal--I added an example of the query.